# Android app polls bluetooth devices and freezes after 80min

Tags: android, bluetooth, freeze, polling

Together with a sub-company we try to develop an android app which simulates an automotive HMI system. There is a functionality to changes the color-theme in case of connected mobile-phone (via Bluetooth). In general this is working: If a known paired phone is in range the theme switches... if the phone loses connection the theme switches back...

Problem: Currently the app polls the paired bluetooth devices for every second and checks if a known phone is paired.
After ~1h and 20min (+/- 5min) the app freezes (reproducible).
Our sub-company told us, that the reason is a problem in android bluetooth device - A timer overflows and android refuses the requests of the app after this time. Thats the reason, that the app freezes.

I´m not familiar with android development and I have to believe in this statements.

Could you tell me if there are other possibilities?
Is it necessary to poll the bluetooth device? Is there nothing like an system event which could be used?
Is this problem (refused bluetooth pooling after defined time) known?

Hint: The problem occurs only with power supply. In battery usage the app runs till battery is empty (longer than 80min).

Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro with android 4.4 (same problem with android 4.3)

It would be nice if anybody is able to help.

Many thanks

Comment: What bluetooth profile is being used?

Comment: I don´t know - I have to check this with the sub-company

Comment: What happens when the phone is put into keep screen on mode?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the phone is coupled or not, nor if a known phone is in range. The problem is, that the app polls the bluetooth interface for known devices. The app freezes after 80mins independ if a known phone was found and coupled in this time or not... the app freezes always. I can leave the running app 80mins without any user interaction. It will freeze anyway only because of the polling

Comment: I'm thinking for you.  You owe me something.  You should be using the bluetooth battery profile and the bluetooth signal profile to determine connectivity with the HID (that's why I asked).  Because users need to know battery and antenna strength all the time.  And do me a favor this is the part you owe me on.  Don't display individual bars for the battery but instead display a solid bar that accurately represents the % full int 0-100 reported by the battery profile.